# Usage of ExportXML and ImportXML using RichTextXMLhandler in Wxpython 4.0

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I have building simple application using the Richtextctrl in wxPython 4.0.0a1(Latest version) and using python 2.7.

I have tried to save the buffer content using richtextxmlhandler with savestrem method, but in the latest version wxpython savestrem methon is not available.

so. i used the ExportXML,but i am getting errors. please any example on usage of Exportxml in rich text is helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RichTextCtrl` had the `SaveStream` method removed in Phoenix. So now you need to use `SaveFile`:

```
# wxPython Phoenix / Python 3 Version

import wx
import wx.richtext

from io import BytesIO


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Richtext Test')

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.rt = wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl(self)
        self.rt.SetMinSize((300,200))

        save_button = wx.Button(self, label="Save")
        save_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_save)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.rt, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 6)
        sizer.Add(save_button, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 6)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()

    def on_save(self, event):
        out = BytesIO()
        handler = wx.richtext.RichTextXMLHandler()
        rt_buffer = self.rt.GetBuffer()
        handler.SaveFile(rt_buffer, out)
        self.xml_content = out.getvalue()
        print(self.xml_content)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You can read more about SaveFile here:

- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl.html#wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl.SaveFile

I also updated my blog article on this topic here:

- https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2015/07/10/wxpython-extracting-xml-from-the-richtextctrl/

Comment: I am using wxPython 4.0.0a1(Alpha version). I created application taking example from your blog post. https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2015/07/10/wxpython-extracting-xml-from-the-richtextctrl/. I have used RichtextXMLhandler method ExportXML instead of Savestrem. It doesn't work for me.  I have tried 
with Richtextctrl SaveFile method, but it throwing error as "The text couldn't be saved"

Comment: My bad. wxPython did actually remove the SaveStream method after all. I had forgotten that. Anyway, I updated the article you mentioned as well as my answer. Note that my answer assumes you're using Python 3. If you're not, then you'll have to swap out the `io` stuff and re-add the `StringIO` bits.

Comment: ,It's working for me. Thanks for your answer and help